# The multi_vowel_words function returns all words with 3 or more consecutive vowels (a, e, i, o, u). Fill in the regular expression to do that

Tags: python, regex, substring, python-re

```py
import re
def multi_vowel_words(text):
  pattern = r"\b(?=[a-z]*[aeiou]{3})[a-z]+\b"
  result = re.findall(pattern, text)
  return result
print(multi_vowel_words("Obviously, the queen is courageous and gracious."))
# Should be ['Obviously', 'queen', 'courageous', 'gracious']
```

the output I got:-
`['queen', 'courageous', 'gracious']`
help me to Get the desired output with the correct pattern

Comment: Hint: `Obviously` starts with a capital letter...

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework assignment. But to add to Nick's hint: `{3}` means match exactly 3.

Answer (score 3):

I would keep it simple and match on the pattern `\b\w*[aeiou]{3}\w*\b` in case insensitive mode:

```py
def multi_vowel_words(text):
    return re.findall(r'\b\w*[aeiou]{3}\w*\b', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

inp = "Obviously, the queen is courageous and gracious."
words = multi_vowel_words(inp)
print(words)  # ['Obviously', 'queen', 'courageous', 'gracious']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the letters before and after the pattern in an easier way.

```
pattern = r'(\w*.[a,e,i,o,u]{2,}\w*)'
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex pattern **r"\b[\w]*[aeiou]{3,}[\w]*"** will match words with 3 or more consecutive vowels **{3,}** , including word starting with capital letters **\b[\w]***

```py
import re

def multi_vowel_words(text):
  pattern = r"\b[\w]*[aeiou]{3,}[\w]*"
  result = re.findall(pattern, text)
  return result

print(multi_vowel_words("Obviously, the queen is courageous and gracious.")) 
# ['Obviously', 'queen', 'courageous', 'gracious']
```